# aiboto3 in Lambda Function Container: Runtime Error: No module named 'botocore.compress'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, botocore, aiobotocore

I use containerized lambda functions.

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade boto3 # Just to be safe
RUN pip install --upgrade botocore # Just to be safe

COPY ./main.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD ["main.lambda_handler"]
```

This is main.py.

```
import asyncio
import aioboto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    key = "test"
    bucket = "test"
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(test_key(bucket, key))
    return result


async def test_key(bucket: str, key: str):
    try:
        session = aioboto3.Session()
        async with session.client("s3") as client:
            response = await client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False
```

requirements.txt

```
aioboto3
asyncio
```

When invoking the function (either locally or inside an online Lambda environment) I get the following error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'botocore.compress'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "87dcc2be-d84c-4725-8f2f-663219c6f43c", "stackTrace": []}
```

Comment: A small additional information: 
I attached a shell to the container, started python and successfully ran "import botocore.compress".

Comment: Even running  `from main import lambda_handler` and then `lambda_handler(None, None)`works like a charm.

Comment: What version of botocore is actually running, `either locally or inside an online Lambda environment`? The `botocore.compress` file has only been part of botocore since 1.31.14: https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/bf00aa7f48eff88666cda6e4d2799e8adf9be50e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this has to do with how AWS is running the Python images. From my experiments outlined below, it does not appear that Lambda uses the `botocore` inside the image; the image is treated as just a "box" for the files. The execution environment, including the version of `botocore`, is provided by the Lambda service.

At the time of writing, Python 3.9 and 3.10 images are using boto3+botocore 1.26.90, while Python 3.11 using `1.34.34`. As Bert have highlighted above, `botocore>=1.31.14` is required for `botocore.compress`, so currently Python 3.9 and 3.10 would not be able to run `aioboto3` at all.

The test is conducted by a simple `lambda_handler` of:

```py
import json
import sys


def lambda_handler(event, context) -> dict:
    import boto3
    import botocore
    try:
        import aioboto3

        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps(
                {
                    "python": sys.version,
                    "aioboto3": aioboto3.__version__,
                    "boto3": boto3.__version__,
                    "botocore": botocore.__version__,
                }
            ),
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        }

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": json.dumps(
                {
                    "python": sys.version,
                    "boto3": boto3.__version__,
                    "botocore": botocore.__version__,
                    "error": {"kind": type(e).__name__, "message": str(e)},
                }
            ),
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        }
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10 AS app
ARG PIP_INSTALL

RUN ${PIP_INSTALL} aioboto3

COPY image/ .

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

`public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11` returns:

```py
{'python': '3.11.6 (main, Dec  4 2023, 13:34:04) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17)]',
 'aioboto3': '12.3.0',
 'boto3': '1.34.34',
 'botocore': '1.34.34'}
```

`public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10` returns:

```py
{'python': '3.10.13 (main, Dec  4 2023, 13:30:46) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17)]',
 'boto3': '1.26.90',
 'botocore': '1.29.90',
 'error': {'kind': 'ModuleNotFoundError',
  'message': "No module named 'botocore.compress'"}}
```

`public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9` returns:

```py
{'python': '3.9.18 (main, Dec  4 2023, 13:30:08) \n[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-17)]',
 'boto3': '1.26.90',
 'botocore': '1.29.90',
 'error': {'kind': 'ModuleNotFoundError',
  'message': "No module named 'botocore.compress'"}}


In a nutshell - try migrating your code to py3.11 if possible!
```